# Use box-sizing: "border-box" and keep image dimensions

Tags: css

If I use `box-sizing: "border-box"` for images the images will get smaller, like on hover: [Example JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BPRyZ/)

Is it possible to do the same effect without the image getting cropped?

Comment: Using just an `<img>` element, no. You'd have to use a combination of `background-size` and so forth.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Solution #1** Outline property. Try to use `outline` instead of border with negative [outline-offset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/outline-offset) value equal to outline width:

```
img:hover {
    box-sizing:border-box;
    outline: solid 10px #f80;
    outline-offset: -10px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dfsq/BPRyZ/2/

Also since IE does not understand this property you can leave `box-sizing` to be used by IE8+.

**Solution #2** Using div as wrapper + `:after`:

```
<div class="img-wrap">
    <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/af/Bonsai_IMG_6426.jpg" class="img1" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.img-wrap:after {
    border: 0;
}
.img-wrap:hover:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    border: solid 10px #f80;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dfsq/BPRyZ/7/

Comment: Been searching for this for HOURS.

Answer (score 3):

The question you need to answer is, do you want the image itself to be 200px, or the entire box to be 200px.  There are 4 different ways to code this depending on your answer to the previous question...

**If you want the entire box to be 200px wide, then you can use border-box with the following code...**

http://jsfiddle.net/BPRyZ/8/

```
img {
    width:200px;
    border: transparent 10px solid;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}

img:hover{
    box-sizing:border-box;
    border:solid 10px #f80;
}
```

**If you want the entire box to be 200px wide, then you could also use this code...**

```
img {
    width:180px;
    border: transparent 10px solid;
}

img:hover{
    border:solid 10px #f80;
}
```

**If you want the image itself to be 200px, then you need this code... (this means your total box width is actually 220px)**

```
img {
    width:220px;
    border: transparent 10px solid;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}

img:hover{
    box-sizing:border-box;
    border:solid 10px #f80;
}
```

**For the above you could also use...**

```
img {
    width:200px;
    border: transparent 10px solid;
}

img:hover{
    border:solid 10px #f80;
}
```

Comment: Hi I don't want to make the image "smaller" or change its position on the document

Comment: Thank you, but Im screen scraping the images, I dont have much control over there css, In most cases I dont want to change there CSS either

Answer (score 1):

I updated your [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/BPRyZ/3/)

CSS:

```
img {
    width:200px;
    border: transparent 10px solid;
}

img:hover{
    box-sizing:border-box;
    border:solid 10px #f80;
    width:220px;
}
```

Comment: Better to use `border: transparent 10px solid;`.